# InitializeComponent removed when adding any event

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a strange problem. I have installed Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows on Windows 8.1 (upgraded from 8, and 8 was clean install). It creates new c# projects without problems, adds controls to the pages, but when I add any event for any control, it just removes InitializeComponent, and I get exception that there is no definition for it. This happens both if I add event from designer or when I edit XAML code to add event.

It is interesting that it opens other projects that contain events normally.

Is there some fix for this?

Comment: Just to note that I have installed Visual Studio Express 2012 after posting this and it works without a problem...

Answer (score 0):

Restart of Visual Studio resolves the problem.